# How do you use javascript event listeners for mobile navigation menus?

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, menu

I'm pretty confident there are some details about the way event listeners work that I haven't quite figured out yet. I am trying to make a mobile navigation menu that will slide in and fill the viewport when the menu bars are selected and disappear when A) the bars are selected again and B) when a user clicks on a link.

I am using vanilla javascript html and css for this and have been fiddling around with html checkboxes and event listeners for a day or two trying to figure it out. I've had *some* luck but not enough to get it fully functional. I'm hoping someone can help me out!

So far the menu will appear when the bars are selected. Great - that's what I wanted. 
My issue is that after a link is clicked and the menu disappears, the functionality of the event listener for the bars just stops working. Can someone explain why that is? I linked the codepen below.

I *think* it's doing something similar to this... 
start: open menu is false, 
click menu icon: open menu is true, 
click menu icon: open menu is false, 
click menu icon: open menu is true, 
click link inside menu: open menu is false, 
click menu icon: open menu is false <<< i could be wrong but anyway, i still don't want this. not sure how to "reset" the value after a link is selected.

```
[CodePen][1]


  [1]: https://codepen.io/finamoss/pen/mdegbMP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never removing the class of .close-menu when you click on the nav button, so you still have that class applied which is setting the position of the nav off-screen.

Comment: Well, that was the easier solution ever. Thank you!